# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 - google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to send data from a html form to google sheets document. I keep getting the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" error. Can someone please provide assistance?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
            <meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
            <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>
        </head>

        <body>

            <!-- Contact Form - sent to a Google Sheet -->

            <form id='foo'>

        <p>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input id='name' name='name' type='text'>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input id='email' name='email' type='email'>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input id='phone' name='phone' type='tel'>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea id='message' name='message' rows='5'></textarea>
        </p>

            <div id='success'></div>
                <button type='submit'>Send</button>
            </form>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
        <script src='google-sheet.js'></script>
    </html>
```

I am attempting to send data from a html form to google sheets document. I keep getting the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" error. Can someone please provide assistance?

google-sheet.js

```
// Variable to hold request
var request;

// Bind to the submit event of our form
     $("#foo").submit(function(event){

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "https://script.google.com/macros/u/0/s/AKfycbzBcGD8jJ2fblphRDVkwtxjUm23TNawFXPHPqZ4wZAyP-EfWQ/exec",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData


    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        console.log(response);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I am attempting to send data from a html form to google sheets document. I keep getting the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" error. Can someone please provide assistance?

google script

```
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "FormSheet";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

    var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function

    function doGet(e){
      return handleResponse(e);
    }

    function doPost(e){
    return handleResponse(e);
    }

    function handleResponse(e) {

  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations

      var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
      lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

      try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations

        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data

        var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
        var row = [];

    // loop through the header columns

        for (i in headers){
          if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
            row.push(new Date());
          } else { // else use header name to get data    
            row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
          }
        }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually

        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results

        return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
      } catch(e){

    // if error return this

        return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
      } finally { //release lock
        lock.releaseLock();
      }
    }

    function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
    }
```

The Form:

[image]

Comment: I will need to see your code.

Comment: Cooper, I added the code, do you see anything missing

Comment: I think it may be failing to load this resource: `<script src='google-sheet.js'></script>`

Comment: Any idea why? I have it saved in the same directory as the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Use google.script.run.  With it you can run any script that is inside of your project.  [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

This is a simple example of a web app that puts an editable spreadsheet on an HTML Page.  Publish as a webapp.

Code.gs:

```
var SSID='SpreadsheetID';
var sheetName='Sheet Name';
function htmlSpreadsheet(mode)
{
  var mode=(typeof(mode)!='undefined')?mode:'dialog';
  var br='<br />';
  var s='';
  var hdrRows=1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  s+='<table>';
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(i<hdrRows)
      {
        s+='<th id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="10" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      } 
      else
      {
        s+='<td id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="10" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      }
    }
    s+='</tr>';
  }
  s+='</table>';
  //s+='<div id="success"></div>';
  s+='</body></html>';
  switch (mode)
  {
    case 'dialog':
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
      userInterface.append(s);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Spreadsheet Data for ' + ss.getName() + ' Sheet: ' + sht.getName());
      break;
    case 'web':
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
      return userInterface.append(s).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
   }
}

function updateSpreadsheet(i,j,value)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  rngA[i][j]=value;
  rng.setValues(rngA);
  var data = {'message':'Cell[' + Number(i + 1) + '][' + Number(j + 1) + '] Has been updated', 'ridx': i, 'cidx': j};
  return data;
}

function doGet()
{
  var output=htmlSpreadsheet('web');
  return output;
}
```

htmlss.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    });
    function updateSS(i,j)
    {
      var str='#txt' + String(i) + String(j);
      var value=$(str).val();
      $(str).css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(successHandler)
         .updateSpreadsheet(i,j,value)
    }
    function successHandler(data)
    {
      $('#success').text(data.message);
      $('#txt' + data.ridx + data.cidx).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    }
    console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      th{text-align:left}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="success"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" error
**check ur libary files this is the one of the resource** and another thing
I dont Know but it might be work for u
**share your Spreadsheet acroos your domain(if not works then try another share options) then u will not get that error**